# Webdriver.io for Android/IOS saucelabs

Tags: saucelabs

Im trying to run selenium webdriver.io in saucelabs for Android /IOS , but the scripts are failing in saucelabs  what is the optimal configuration capabilities  that are recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Android:

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "souce-storage:***.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        capabilities.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.5.3");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(URL), capabilities);
```